# ghost question in hello-world tag

Tags: support, tags, burninate-system, locked-posts

I've been checking on the [hello-world](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hello-world) tag after starting to burninate it last week. It seems like burnination was successful. On the [main tag page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hello-world) it shows 0 questions are tagged, but the tag has survived the overnight tag cleanup process and on the [top users page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/hello-world/topusers) it shows 1 question.

Is this because of a question that was deleted? If so, could a mod remove the tag from it so the tag can die?

Comment: It was still on a [locked question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/284797/revisions).

Comment: @animuson Isn't that question a good candidate for migration to the codegolf site? Or does age preclude that?